# Is there anything we can add to the IVP so that it will be equivalent to continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm looking for equivalent  definitions of continuity (of real functions) that could agree beter with the intuition everyone has before a formal course in real analysis.

In that search, I thought it would be cool if some properties we want continuous functions to have, such that the intermediate value property (IVP) or the existence of extreme values on compact sets, could be enough to ensure continuity.

I know that none of those two are enough to imply continuity, and I also know that you can impose some conditions (as monotonicity) so that the IVP implies continuity. But I'm looking for a general result in the following way:

> A function $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous iff
> it satisfies the IVP and (Property 1), (Property 2), ... ,(Property
> n).

Obviously, it would be desirable that the properties involved were all as intuitive from what we expect from continuity as the IVT, but learning about any such characterization would be great anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X,Y$ be two topological space. $f: X\to Y$ is a Darboux function if $f(A) \subset Y$ pathconnected for all $A\subset X$ pathconnected.

If $X$ is locally connected and first countable and $Y$ is Hausdorff.Then $f$ is continuous iff $f$ is Darboux function and preserve compact sets.

In your  settings $(\Bbb{R}, \tau_{std}) $ is locally connected, first countable and Hausdorff. Hence

$f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous iff $f$ is a Darboux function ( i.e has IVP) and $f$ maps compact sets to compact sets.

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful but how can I prove it?